# Какой длины должен быть фиксированный заголовок в веб запросе

Tags: веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

У меня есть сервер и клиент, они общаются через tcp клиент. Прежде чем будет обработано тело читает заголовок, в котором длина тела запроса указана. Так вот, какой длины делать этот заголовок? Ведь тело может быть достаточно большим и есть вероятность что вся длина не уместится в фиксированный заголовок - ну, такие опасения у меня )

Comment: Почему бы не указать и длину заголовка тоже?

Comment: А как её считывать?? Считывается конкретная длина байт

Comment: Почему бы не сделать длине конкретную длину байт?